# Transformar consulta de MySQL a Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Tengo esta query en MySQL:

```
select p.id_empleado as id,(select 'empleado') as tipo, p.url_imagen, concat_ws(' ',p.nombre,p.paterno,p.materno) as nombre,
        e.nombre as empresa,concat_ws(' ',u.nombre,u.apellidos) as solicitante, p.fecha_alta, p.estado
from empleados p inner join usuarios u on p.id_usuario = u.id_usuario 
                 inner join empresas e on u.id_empresa = e.id_empresa
union
select p.id_alumno as id,(select 'estudiante') as tipo, p.url_imagen, concat_ws(' ',p.nombre,p.paterno,p.materno) as nombre,
        e.nombre as empresa,concat_ws(' ',u.nombre,u.apellidos) as solicitante, p.fecha_alta, p.estado
from estudiantes p inner join usuarios u on p.id_alumno = u.id_usuario 
                 inner join empresas e on u.id_empresa = e.id_empresa
```

y transformarlo a una consulta con estilo de codeigniter, por ejemplo:

```
$this->db->select('title, content, date');
$query = $this->db->get('mytable');
```

es igual a:

```
SELECT title, content, date FROM mytable
```

Lo que se me ocurre es hacerlo con `$this->db->query()`, pero en mi caso no me funcionaria porque quiero obtener los resultados en otra función por ejemplo:

```
funcion 1{
            $this->db->from("ejemplo");

}
funcion 2{
        $this->funcion1();        
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
}
```

La verdad es que no se por donde empezar, si me ayudar en algo seria de mucha ayuda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ActiveRecord](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/active_record.html) no tiene soporte para UNION, por lo que solo debes escribir tu consulta y utilizar el método de consulta de ActiveRecord.

Quedaría de esta manera:

```
$this->db->query("SELECT p.id_empleado as id,(select 'empleado') as tipo, p.url_imagen, concat_ws(' ',p.nombre,p.paterno,p.materno) as nombre,
                    e.nombre as empresa,concat_ws(' ',u.nombre,u.apellidos) as solicitante, p.fecha_alta, p.estado
            from empleados p inner join usuarios u on p.id_usuario = u.id_usuario 
                             inner join empresas e on u.id_empresa = e.id_empresa
            UNION
            select p.id_alumno as id,(select 'estudiante') as tipo, p.url_imagen, concat_ws(' ',p.nombre,p.paterno,p.materno) as nombre,
                    e.nombre as empresa,concat_ws(' ',u.nombre,u.apellidos) as solicitante, p.fecha_alta, p.estado
            from estudiantes p inner join usuarios u on p.id_alumno = u.id_usuario 
                             inner join empresas e on u.id_empresa = e.id_empresa");
```

Otra alternativa, por si quieres mantener el estándar con ActiveRecord:

```
// #1 SubQueries no.1 -------------------------------------------
$this->db->select("p.id_empleado as id,(select 'empleado') as tipo, p.url_imagen, concat_ws(' ',p.nombre,p.paterno,p.materno) as nombre,
                    e.nombre as empresa,concat_ws(' ',u.nombre,u.apellidos) as solicitante, p.fecha_alta, p.estado");
$this->db->from('empleados p');
$this->db->join('usuarios u', 'p.id_usuario = u.id_usuario', 'inner');
$this->db->join('empresas e', 'u.id_empresa = e.id_empresa', 'inner');
$query = $this->db->get();
$subQuery1 = $this->db->_compile_select();
$this->db->_reset_select();
// #2 SubQueries no.2 -------------------------------------------
$this->db->select("p.id_alumno as id,(select 'estudiante') as tipo, p.url_imagen, concat_ws(' ',p.nombre,p.paterno,p.materno) as nombre,
                e.nombre as empresa,concat_ws(' ',u.nombre,u.apellidos) as solicitante, p.fecha_alta, p.estado");
$this->db->from('estudiantes p');
$this->db->join('usuarios u', 'p.id_usuario = u.id_usuario', 'inner');
$this->db->join('empresas e', 'u.id_empresa = e.id_empresa', 'inner');
$query = $this->db->get();
$subQuery2 = $this->db->_compile_select();
$this->db->_reset_select();

// #3 Union manual --------------------------
$this->db->query("select * from ($subQuery1 UNION $subQuery2) as unionTable");

// #3 Alternativa con ActiveRecord ------------
$this->db->from("($subQuery1 UNION $subQuery2)");
$this->db->get();
```

Comment: y no habra otra forma de añadir una tabla debajo de la otra sin usar "query"? al momento tengo la primera consulta antes del union: $this->db->select("p.id_alumno as id,'empleado' as tipo, p.url_imagen, concat_ws(' ',p.nombre,p.paterno,p.materno) as nombre,
                            e.nombre as empresa,concat_ws(' ',u.nombre,u.apellidos) as solicitante, p.fecha_alta, p.estado");
            $this->db->from("estudiantes p");
            $this->db->join("usuarios u","p.id_alumno=u.id_usuario","inner");
            $this->db->join("empresas e","u.id_empresa=e.id_empresa","inner");

Comment: @U.C, si hay, ahorita edito mi respuesta con otras alternativas

Comment: muchas gracias.

Comment: @U.C espero se comprenda la idea

Comment: @U.C Solo ten cuidado con las comillas simples y dobles

Comment: perfecto me funciono, muchas gracias